# SQL column with list of foreign keys

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am working with Python, PostgreSQL, SQLAlchemy and alembic.

I have to design a database, but I am kinda stuck because my design needs to have a column which will store a list of IDs which are basically foreign keys. I am not sure how to do that and moreover if I should be doing that.

Example: I have a discount table which basically contains all the available discount codes.I have a column discount_applies to where I want to store a list of all products to which the discount applies (I cannot edit the products table). Basically the column will contain a list of UUIDs of products on which the discount can be applied

Comment: OK so you have a list of products with product_id and you want a new table with discount codes as well as product_id correct?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty standard many to many relationship.  Given the difficulty this is presenting you, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @Stivan Yes. In my new discount code table a discount code can be applied to multiple products, therefore the column discount_applies_to needs to be a list of product ids.

Comment: @Priyam Then in this new table you only need 2 columns with no Primary Key. `discount_applies_to` should be a Foreign Key to Products table and `discount_code` is just a regular column storing the discounts. So you should have 3 tables to create this relationship. Products,Dicounts(list of all codes and description), Dicounted_prod (the table wich will create relationship of products and discounts). If this is still unclear I can explain further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Product(Base):
    .....


class Discount(Base):
    .....

class ProductDiscount(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'discount_applies'

    product_id = Column(String(32), nullable=False, ,ForeignKey('product.id'))
    discount_id = Column(String(32), nullable=False,ForeignKey('discount.id')) #If discount primary key if Integer then change String to Integer
    product = relationship(Product)
    discount = relationship(Discount)
```

Comment: I am not sure what is relationship(Person)

Comment: Sorry.. Updated my answer